# Query issue ranking system MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, ranking

I have a ranking system where I save the users rank and points for every game day.[image]

Now my problem is that I want to fetch the number of rank-positions that a user have climbed since last day. So in this example the user_id = 1 has dropped 3 positions since yesterday. My current query is giving me kind of what I want, but with some extra calculation that I want to remove. So my question is how do I calculate the difference in rank for every user (between today and yesterday)?
[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b040c/5)

Comment: Do you want to compare "Today" and "Yesterday" only *(17th March vs 16th March)*?  Or do you want Every row in your table compared against the day before?  And does every user have a record for every day, or can there be gaps?

Comment: You also need to add `current.user_id = last.user_id` to your SQL *(as part of the `LEFT JOIN`)*.

Comment: No my i just want to compare today with yesterday for this query. And yes every user will have a record for every day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT current.user_id,(last.rank -current.rank)
FROM ranking as current
LEFT JOIN ranking as last ON 
last.user_id = current.user_id
WHERE current.rank_date = (SELECT max(rank_date) FROM ranking)
and
last.rank_date = (SELECT max(rank_date) FROM ranking 
 where rank_date <  (SELECT max(rank_date) FROM ranking)               
                 )
```

Comment: Did you look at the OPS SQLFiddle example?

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest way is:

```
SELECT today.user_id, (yest.rank - today.rank) as diff
FROM ranking today JOIN
     ranking yest
     on today.user_id = yest.user_id 
WHERE today.rank_date = CURRENT_DATE AND
      yest.rank_date = date_sub(CURRENT_DATE, interval 1 day);
```

Answer (score 0):

> So my question is how do I calculate the difference in rank for every
>   user (between today and yesterday)?

with regard to your sqlfiddle demo I think you want this output:

```
user_id diff
1       3
1       -3
2       -1
2       -1
```

So try this:

```
SELECT current.user_id,(last.rank - current.rank) as diff
FROM ranking as current
LEFT JOIN ranking as last 
ON last.rank_date = current.rank_date+1
   and last.user_id = current.user_id
where last.rank_date is not null
order by current.user_id
```

Comment: `ON last.rank_date = current.rank_date+1` should be `-1` to get "the previous date"